# How can I resolve 'failed to parse request' error when scanning vulnerable opensources with JFrog Xray and Artifactory?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli, jfrog-xray

When I do JFrog Xray Scan function to the opensource that containied vulnerability, there are logs that indicate "failed to parse request,: request is missing package id".

And there are no security results with vulnerabilities.

I have tested some opensources like openssl, curl etc...

JFrog Artifactory: 7.55.10

JFrog Xray: 3.71.7

License: Trial License (Before I buy Pro X License, I have tested JFrog Xray with Trial license.)

Package: Generic

Is there a way to resolve this problem?

Also is JFrog Xray able to scan source code and binary with Pro X license?

Organizing Information

- Repository / Package Type: Local Repository / Generic
- App Version: JFrog Artifactory 7.55.10 / JFrog Xray 3.71.7
- License: Trial version.
- Test Data: Opensource e.g. openssl 1.1.1q
- Log:

```
[WARN]  [rise_configuration_service]  [main  ]  feature is not supported, no execution path exist.
[ERROR]  [http_handler_ext]  [main  ]  Failed to parse request: request is missng package id  --- at /go/src/jfrog.com/xray/backend/handlers/component/component_handler_utils.go
```

Comment: Please provide some more information such as - the command that you ran, the project or package type, logs...

Comment: I just did scan function on the web to check openssl 1.1.1q
Of course, I have tried using REST API to scan it.
e.g curl -u <id:password> -X POST -d "content-type: application/json" "https://{url}/xray/api/v1/scanArtifact"
The result of upper statement is that scan of artifacts is in progress.
As I said, I deployed it on my local repository which package type is generic.